# How to add numbers when they have same category?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code I am trying so far

```
let data = [
{size: 1180160, category: "Keswick", index: 1},
{size: 1059328, category: "HCOPA", index: 2},
{size: 30720, category: "HCOPA", index: 3},
{size: 493056, category: "Darhan Saluja", index: 4},
{size: 267776, category: "CRSA", index: 5},:
{size: 328704, category: "Arundel", index: 6}
{size: 73216, category: "Arundel", index: 7}

data.forEach((product, index) => {

           let size = 0;
           if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
             size = product.size + size;
             rows.push(
                <ProductCategoryRow size={size}
                                    category={product.category}
                                    key={product.category}/>
            );
        }
        rows.push(
            <ProductRow
                product={product}
                key={product.name} index={index}/>
        );
        lastCategory = product.category;

    });
```

I want calculate size which have same category. So that will pass through as props to component

Comment: when exactly do you want to render ProductCategoryRow and ProductRow, can you elaborate more on what you want to do

Comment: why don't you iterate through data first and make required data adding same category. and then iterate over it for component. it would be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create new object first that contains all data you need with sum up of properties that you need and then use that object to perform whatever logic you need.

Look at the snippet below and feel free to adjust it to your needs.

```js
let data = [
{size: 1180160, category: "Keswick", index: 1},
{size: 1059328, category: "HCOPA", index: 2},
{size: 30720, category: "HCOPA", index: 3},
{size: 493056, category: "Darhan Saluja", index: 4},
{size: 267776, category: "CRSA", index: 5},
{size: 328704, category: "Arundel", index: 6},
{size: 73216, category: "Arundel", index: 7}]

const dataWithSum = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  acc[current.category] = acc[current.category] ? acc[current.category] + current.size : current.size;
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(dataWithSum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create chunks of your data and then render it like

```
let data = [
{size: 1180160, category: "Keswick", index: 1},
{size: 1059328, category: "HCOPA", index: 2},
{size: 30720, category: "HCOPA", index: 3},
{size: 493056, category: "Darhan Saluja", index: 4},
{size: 267776, category: "CRSA", index: 5},
{size: 328704, category: "Arundel", index: 6},
{size: 73216, category: "Arundel", index: 7}]

const chunk = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if(acc[item.category]) {
      acc[item.category] = acc[item.category].concat(item)
    } else {
      acc[item.category] = [item];
   }
   return acc
}, {})

Object.keys(chunk).forEach((category, index) => {
   rows.push(
      <ProductCategoryRow 
          size={size}
          category={category}
          key={category}/>
  );
  chunk[category].forEach((product, index)) => {
     rows.push(
        <ProductRow
            product={product}
            key={product.name}/>
     );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and `findIndex`. `findIndex` will be used to find if the new array have any object where the category matches.If it does then update the size else add the category name and it's size

```js
let data = [{
    size: 1180160,
    category: "Keswick",
    index: 1
  },
  {
    size: 1059328,
    category: "HCOPA",
    index: 2
  },
  {
    size: 30720,
    category: "HCOPA",
    index: 3
  },
  {
    size: 493056,
    category: "Darhan Saluja",
    index: 4
  },
  {
    size: 267776,
    category: "CRSA",
    index: 5
  },
  {
    size: 328704,
    category: "Arundel",
    index: 6
  }, {
    size: 73216,
    category: "Arundel",
    index: 7
  }
]


var reduceCat = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  // find the index of the category
  // return -1 if the category is not present
  var ifCatAvailable = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return curr.category === item.category;
  })
  // if category is not present then 
  // add the category and it's size
  if (ifCatAvailable === -1) {
    let locObj = {
      category: curr.category,
      size: curr.size
    }
    acc.push(locObj)
    // if catgory is present then update it's size
  } else {
    acc[ifCatAvailable].size += curr.size
  }
  return acc;

}, []);
console.log(reduceCat)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also create the array of categories 
and put the result in an array result = [ categorie, size ]

```
let data = [
{size: 1180160, category: "Keswick", index: 1},
{size: 1059328, category: "HCOPA", index: 2},
{size: 30720, category: "HCOPA", index: 3},
{size: 493056, category: "Darhan Saluja", index: 4},
{size: 267776, category: "CRSA", index: 5},
{size: 328704, category: "Arundel", index: 6},
{size: 73216, category: "Arundel", index: 7}];

let categories = [];
let result = [];

data.forEach((product, index) => {
            if( !categories.includes(product.category) ) {
              categories.push(product.category);
              result.push({
                category : product.category,
                size: product.size
                });
            }
            else{
              result.find(x => x.category === product.category).size += product.size;
            }    
    });
console.log(data, categories, result);
```